# Smart contract testing - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to test an ERC20 contract that I've written. It keeps on returning the following errors when I run truffle test:

```
    ✓ Should deploy smart contract properly
    1) "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library"
    2) "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library"


  1 passing (172ms)
  2 failing

  1) Contract: My
       "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library":
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at /Users/.../test/myToken.js:8:47
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

  2) Contract: My
       "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library":
     Error: done() called multiple times in hook <Contract: MyToken "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library"> of file ...


UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at /Users/.../myToken.js:8:47
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    uncaught: true,
    multiple: [ [Error] ]
  }
} TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at /Users/.../myToken.js:8:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  uncaught: true,
  multiple: [
    Error: done() called multiple times in hook <Contract: MyToken "before each" hook: before test for "should call a function that depends on a linked library"> of file /Users/.../myToken.js
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      code: 'ERR_MOCHA_MULTIPLE_DONE',
      valueType: 'undefined',
      value: undefined
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't understand what is going on. I practically copied this passage of code from the tuffle documentation so everything should be running. What am I missing?

This is my code.

````
const { assert } = require("console");

const MyContract = artifacts.require("My");

contract("MyToken", accounts => {
  it("Should deploy smart contract properly", () => {
    MyContract.deployed()
      .then((instance) => instance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]))
      .then((balance) => {
        assert.equal(
          balance.valueOf(),
          10000,
          "10000 wasn't in the first account"
      );
  });
});

it("should call a function that depends on a linked library", () => {
  let my;
  let myBalance; 
  let myEthBalance; 
  return myBalance.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
      my = instance; 
      return my.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    })
    .then(outCoinBalance => {
      myBalance = outCoinBalance.toNumber();
      return my.getBalanceInEth.call(accounts[0]);
    })
    .then(outCoinBalanceEth => {
      myEthBalance = outCoinBalanceEth.toNumber();
    })
    .then(() => {
      assert.equal(myEthBalance,
        2 * myBalance,
        "Library function returned unexpected function, linkage may be broken"
      );
    });
  });

it("should send coin correctly", () => {
  let my;
  // Get initial balances of first and second account. 
  const account_one = accounts[0];
  const account_two = accounts[1];

  let account_one_starting_balance; 
  let account_two_starting_balance; 
  let account_one_ending_balance; 
  let account_two_ending_balance; 

  const amount = 10; 

  return MyContract.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
      my = instance;
      return my.getBalance.call(account_one);
    })
    .then(balance => {
      account_one_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return my.getBalance.call(account_two);
    })
    .then(balance => {
      account_two_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return my.sendCoin(account_two, amount, { from: account_one });
    })
    .then(() => my.getBalance.call(account_one))
    .then(balance => {
      account_one_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return my.getBalance.call(account_two);
    })
    .then(balance => {
      account_two_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

      assert.equal(
        account_one_ending_balance,
        account_one_starting_balance - amount, 
        "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender"
      );
      assert.equal(
        account_two_ending_balance, 
        account_two_starting_balance + amount, 
        "Amount wasn't correctly sent to the receiver"
      );
    });
  });
});```


I have edited some of the names of the variables and the contract names.
````

Comment: means one of `my.getBalance` or the other things you `.call` is undefined ... which one throws the error?

Comment: The last two. The first one worked fine.

Comment: The It("should call a function that depends on a linked library") and the it("should send coin correctly") didn't work. 

Sorry, I am new to JS and solidity